# Authentication for a Read only web application without login screen

Tags: authentication

I have a web based application which is used to find information about various assets in a facility. This provides only search capability, no CRUD operations allowed from the application (except for READ). This web application is always kept open in a touchscreen device (ie workstation) and this could be used by any of the facility staff. The user does not want to initiate login and logout for each of the search operation.

We are planning on deploying the web application onto the cloud. Although it is not a need to authenticate the user who is accessing the web-application, it is still a need to ensure that information about assets in the facility are not accessible by others. How do I build this authentication layer? The various options I can think of are:
1. Include userid/password in the URL as parameters. I could create a userid/password for each of the facility. Simple, but userid/password area always visible.
2. Certificate based approach. Certificates are created for each of these workstations and deployed on those workstations. Quite secure, but has the challenge of managing the certs life-cycle. As well challenge of configuring the web-servers with certs from different facilities???

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but not secure thing. Do an IP check and if the IP is from your facility then grant access.
The second, but secure method is to do a verification at the start of the application with just a password and store a session , so that you will know that people from your facility are accessing the site..

Comment: Thanks Miro. As you mentioned, checking IP-address will not be secure, as well it may not work with the DHCP. Related to your second suggestion, isn't it the same as my first option mentioned in the main thread? The question I have is - how and where would you store the password? If it is part of the URL, doesn't feel like a secure solution.

Comment: So with the second option you have two ways to do it:
1.Set a normal password for the whole system and check the password every time system is closed and opened. with the `isdefined()` function. just say `session_start()` at the start of every file and a `isdefined()` to check if you have already authenticated or no. if no then redirect to login page , if yes then display the requested page..

Comment: and the second option, build a database with the user and passwords of each section then on the whole is the same but do a database query and check the user and password in the login page..

Comment: Here I wrote some simple codes for you to get it.. [Site Pages](http://pastebin.com/da7y407m) / [Login Page](http://pastebin.com/add35W3c) .. Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. I understand how userid/password can be passed and how it can be authenticated on the server side. My question is primarily in a scenario, where I do not want to have a login screen, but still want to authenticate that the request coming from a machine is a valid one. I have already highlighted couple of options in my problem statement.